# Selenium webdriver gecko error: The path to the driver must be set by webdriver.gecko

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, gecko

trying to get selenium working but didn't work and showing me below error.

> Libs:junit4.12, selenium-java-3.4, selenium-server-standalone-3.5

Could anyone take a look and tell me whats wrong with the code or what is 
missing, please.
Every time when I start the test, I get 2 errors.
Screenshot embedded at the bottom showing the error details.

My code as below:

```
    package com.example.tests;

    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.junit.*;
    import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.*;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

    public class TestCase16 {
      private WebDriver driver;
      private String baseUrl;
      private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
      private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

      @Before
      public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        baseUrl = "URL";
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

       System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\ayre1de\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("URL");

       }

      @Test
      public void testCaseAcandoIntranet() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("IDToken1")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("IDToken1")).sendKeys("XXX");
        driver.findElement(By.id("IDToken2")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("IDToken2")).sendKeys("*XXX");
        driver.findElement(By.name("Login.Submit")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.id("yui_patched_v3_18_1_1_1502961326988_317")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='_com_liferay_product_navigation_user_personal_bar_web_portlet_ProductNavigationUserPersonalBarPortlet_sidenavUserToggle']/span/div")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Abmelden")).click();
      }

      @After
      public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        driver.quit();
        String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
        if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
          fail(verificationErrorString);
        }
      }

      private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
        try {
          driver.findElement(by);
          return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      private boolean isAlertPresent() {
        try {
          driver.switchTo().alert();
          return true;
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
          return false;
        }
      }

      private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
        try {
          Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
          String alertText = alert.getText();
          if (acceptNextAlert) {
            alert.accept();
          } else {
            alert.dismiss();
          }
          return alertText;
        } finally {
          acceptNextAlert = true;
        }
      }
    }
    `
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are initializing webdriver instance two times like below. specially you have missed specifying the   `System.setProperty` for the first instance of webdriver where exactly your code is failing:-

```
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();  // 1st instance
    baseUrl = "URL";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\ayre1de\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // 2nd instance
    driver.get("URL");
```

Now delete above two lines and write your code like below :-

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\ayre1de\\Downloads\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("URL");
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I changed the code as below: `public void testCase17() throws Exception {
   
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\\\IDE\\\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\\\geckodriver.exe");
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     driver.get("https://www.acando.de/");
     baseUrl = "https://intranet.acando.de";
   
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("IDToken1")).clear();` but now i'm having a problem with: Unable eo locate element: #IDToken1

Comment: I checked the id and it's the same as in the code 'IDToken1'

Comment: You have a frame there so you need to switch frame first.

Comment: driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("iframe")));